# Block internet access to KM Player in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firewall, blocking

I'm trying to block internet access to KM player in my windows 10 machine. I had done it in my previous laptop by adding a block rule in firewall and it had worked. But in my new machine, it's not working. This is what I have done

1. Start > Windows Defender Firewall
2. Advanced Settings
3. Outbound rules
4. New Rule - I've selected the script `C:\ProgramFiles\KMPlayer\KMPlayer.exe`

Even after this, KMplayer connects to internet. Has anything changed or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**:
There is a banner that says "These settings are being managed by vendor application McAfee Personal Firewall" in the Windows Defender Firewall page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Search for Windows Defender Firewall and make sure you open this and not the one with advanced security.
2. Click "Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall". If this doesn't work, skip to step 4.
3. Uncheck KM player (or any software).
4. Open McAfee (or any other antivirus with firewall) firewall settings and add the rule there. Alternatively, you can disable McAfee firewall and continue from step 2.

Comment: It says "These settings are being managed by vendor application McAfee Personal Firewall".